# Why is the structure of HNO3 have a central atom rather than being linear?

Tags: lewis-structure

Why is the structure of $\ce{HNO3}$ have a central atom rather than being linear?

I know formal charges need to be reduced as much as possible, and if there was a structure with two oxygens and a hydrogen dangling off the nitrogen on one side and with a double bonded oxygen on the other, wouldn't that make all atoms in it have a formal charge of $0$ while obeying all the rules?

To clarify, the order is hydrogen, single bond, oxygen, single bond, oxygen, single bond, nitrogen, double bond, and the last oxygen.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/is-peroxynitrous-acid-an-isomer-of-nitric-acid

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is not nitric acid $\ce{HONO2}$, but it's much less stable existing structural isomer $\ce{HOONO}$. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxynitrous_acid):

> Peroxynitrous acid $(\ce{HNO3})$ is a reactive nitrogen species (RNS). It is the conjugate acid of peroxynitrite $(\ce{ONOO−}).$ It has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\sim 6.8.$ It is formed in vivo from the diffusion-controlled reaction of nitrogen monoxide $(\ce{ON^.})$ and superoxide $(\ce{O2^{.−}}).$ It isomerises with a rate constant of $k = \pu{1.2 s−1},$ a process whereby up to $5\%$ of hydroxyl and nitrogen dioxide radicals may be formed. It oxidises and nitrates aromatic compounds in low yield. The mechanism may involve a complex between the aromatic compound and $\ce{ONOOH},$ and a transition from the *cis*- to the *trans*-configuration of $\ce{ONOOH}.$ Peroxynitrous acid is also important in atmospheric chemistry.

Comment: "Formed in vivo"... Surely they meant in situ

Comment: > A potent oxidant synthesized by the cell during its normal metabolism. Peroxynitrite is formed from the reaction of two free radicals, NITRIC OXIDE and the superoxide anion (SUPEROXIDES). 

[pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/123349)

Comment: @electronpusher No, in vivo, see other comment and this reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15647782

Comment: Tech detail: please note that copy-pasted text (also from Wikipedia) lacks most of the intended formatting and markup features. Whenever possible, those need to be recreated manually with MathJax and Markdown (see my edit).

Comment: @andselisk Well, I have done so intentionally. I admit I have troubles in accepting this quoting approach I am aware of, seeing it being discussed on meta. I still consider it rather Wikipedia content forwarded to SE than imported to SE. Like an ambassy territory the hosting land laws do not apply to.

Comment: @andselisk But OTOH, I usually copy the source code, mostly directly usable , replacing <math> by dollars, what I did not do this time.

Comment: @Poutnik If you open [Wikipedia editing panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Peroxynitrous_acid&action=edit), you'll see numerous markup and formatting marks that actually make the text literate and readable. Unfortunately, one cannot just copy-paste chunks of source text between SE and Wikipedia as both are using different syntax, so that you have to adapt the formatting. While your intention to preserve the original is commendable, it's [readability and literacy that matters as long as the context hasn't been changed](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4494/41328).

Comment: @andselisk When I copy from the Wikipedia source code as the quote, what I usually do, I do necessery adjustment for the formatting functionality.  Formulas are usually 1:1 transferable. But I do so rather to reproduce Wikipedia look than the SE expected standard, even if it is usually the same. Thank you, I have read the discussion before. Unless it is required by moderators and site policy, I will change in quotes only what must be changed, but not more, As there is always a chance the correction may lead to alternate interpretation, even if it did not looked so in time of the correction.

Comment: @Poutnik Well, this is precisely the case when formatting must've been applied, if you were to read that Meta topic carefully. No meaning is (or hardly could be, in this particular example) changed, but the commonly accepted and standardized notations are used in place of plain text. If you want to preserve the original's meaning, this is exactly what you want to do and not just through out in the open what your browser lets you to copy from a web page.

Comment: I do not dispute this particular case now, as I should have copied the source code instead of displayed code, to reproduce the Wikipedia look, or to reformat the displayed text copy. I do agree in this with you and I do thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, there is nothing in principle to stop HNO3 having the structure you have proposed. However, it is also shown that the common anion derived from this has all oxygens equivalent (see e.g. crystal structures, or NMR studies) so that the structure like a fidget-bit is more common.

Answer (score -3):

How exactly linear.First of all atoms inside the atom must be share as many electrons as their electron configuration "tells "them to share(Oxygen must share 2 electrons).Another issue is that nitrogen and oxygen have lone pairs of electrons at their valence orbital and those lone pairs repel the bonding pairs which gives the molecule its shape.

Comment: If you're disagreeing with the possibility of existence of a linear isomer, what about the literature quoted by Poutnik? Please further elaborate your stance.

Comment: Nitrogen makes 5 bonding pairs in HNO3 . Those 5 bonding pairs repel one another forcing the creatipn of non-linear molecule.Also oxygen has two lone pairs , which repel the bonding pairs of the oxygen , creating a non-linear molecule.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your argument. Which structure are you referring to? The typical structure or the peroxo one?

Comment: HNO3 molecule   OONOH

Comment: 5 bonding pairs 2 double bonding pairs 1 single bonding pair.

Comment: And I will another argument O-O single  bond is weaker than the N-O  double bond and weaker than N-O double bond so the molecule has lower energy.

Comment: That way formed.

Comment: I don't find that satisfactory enough as a relevant argument. And anyway, nitrogen has 3 bonds in the peroxo structure, please verify from the link in Poutnik's answer.

Comment: In HNO3 Nitrogen has 2 double covalent bonds and 1 single covalent bonds = 5 bonds.

Comment: @4HonorNDFame No. Please finish General Chemistry.

Comment: What do you mean general chemistry.There is no such thing as general chemistry.