Which tautomer of nitrous acid is more stable?
I found that there are $2$ possible structures for $\text{HNO}_2$, both of which are tautomers comprising a diad system:

Why is the former more stable? It should be so as I have seen this structure everywhere be it in books or on the internet.
I think of charge separation as a reason for the former being more stable, but I don't feel very confident, so I look forward for clarifications

as a general rule of thumb, lesser number of charges is more stable

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/is-peroxynitrous-acid-an-isomer-of-nitric-acid ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116772/why-is-the-structure-of-hno3-have-a-central-atom-rather-than-being-linear/116777

According to what is admittedly an old reference[1], an IR spectrum analysis seems to show two tautomers for nitrous acid, but not the nitro-hydride one. Instead both tautomers have the $\ce{HO–N=O}$ connectivity, with the hydrogen atom lying inside the $\ce{O–N=O}$ bond angle in the cis form and outside the angle in the more stable trans form. No information in front of the paywall indicates why the nitro isomer was rejected; possibly the authors failed to identify any peaks that could have been assigned to a nitrogen-hydrogen bond.
The nitrite ion, $\ce{NO2^-}$, has a three-center four-electron pi bond whose unoccupied antibonding orbital lies predominantly on nitrogen. Therefore bonding to nitrogen is favored with a cationic moiety that can donate pi electrons overlapping this orbital, which extends the pi bond to cover the additional atom bonded to the nitrogen. An alkyl moiety does so by hyperconjugation, an aryl one through its aromatic ring, but no pi-donation mechanism is available with protic hydrogen.
Reference

Llewellyn H. Jones; Richard M. Badger; Gordon E. Moore. "The Infrared Spectrum and the Structure of Gaseous Nitrous Acid". J. Chem. Phys. 19, 1599–1604 (1951).
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1748129.

